# Prove the function bound satisfies the values

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $f(x, y)$ has continuous 2nd partial derivatives, which satisfy $$|f_{xx}| \le M, |f_{xy}| \le M, |f_{yy}| \le M$$ for all $(x, y) \in N = \{(x, y) | (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 \le r^2 \}$, where $M$ is a constant. Let $L_{(a, b)}(x,y)$ be the linearization of $f$ at $(a, b)$.
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle |f(x, y) - L_{(a, b)}(x, y)| \le M[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2]$ for all $(x, y) \in N$.

I get by Taylor's remainder theorem for the 2 variables as

$$|f(x, y) - L_{(a, b)}(x, y)| \le \frac{1}{2} \cdot \bigg ( M(x-a)^2 + M|(x-a)(y-b)| + M(y - b)^2\bigg )$$

But I am unable to get to the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
|(x-a)(y-b)| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left[(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2\right].
$$